# Go Ticker: get status?

Tags: go

I am working on Go program. I can start Ticker as
 '''timer := time.NewTicker(15 * time.Second)'''
but I need to check if the Ticker is stopped or runing.
Is it possible to know ticker running or stopped?

Comment: There's no way to tell if it's stopped, but if design allows, you can write a wrapper type around the timer that keeps that info.

Comment: I do not believe you can see the status of ticker. It does not provide any way for you to get the status. Can you elaborate how you are using it? Maybe I will be able to help then.

Comment: The ticker by itself does not provide the ability to know if it is stopped. You can keep an associated channel and send the signal whenever it is stopped in the code. Please refer to https://gobyexample.com/tickers on how this can be done.

Comment: @MadhanGanesh what it means is Ticker.Stop is a cleanup call like db.Close which should not be called when any dependent resources are working.